# CX_ST_MATCH_ELEMENT:XSLT exception while calling SAP PI service via WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, sap-pi, sap-xi

I have a C# application that communicates with an SAP function module via a an XI/PI web service.

My C# code is using a Visual Studio-generated WCF proxy (generated via the Visual Studio "Add Service Reference..." wizard.

I'm getting a System.ServiceModel.FaultException with the message

> **CX_ST_MATCH_ELEMENT:XSLT exception.System expected element 'EReturn'**

"EReturn" is an array that's used by the response from the function module, but not used for input. I was able to leave this field null with the old webMethods service. Is this message telling me that I need to initialize it for the XI service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Brian, that's what the message means (I initialized to an empty array, and the error went away.)

You have to initialize all complex objects.